# How to hide a form and show a link onclick and also hide the form and show the link when the form is clicked using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to achieve 2 things with my code

1. When I click on the link with id='show-list-form' I want to hide the link and show the form (with id='add-list-item').
2. When the form appears, I want to be able to click on the close button and hide the form and show the link.
3. The link tag has 2 span items (1. Add a list and 2. Add another list) with the class 'placeholder', I want to be able to one of the two depending on if a list is added or not.

I figure point 3 should have some count item to see if there are any list being displayed and show (Add a list if count = 0 or Add another list if count = to 1 or more, however, I'm just not sure how to achieve this. The code below is what I have so far. Your help will be much appreciated.

```js
function toggle_visibility(divId1, divId2){
 if(document.getElementById(divId1).style.display == 'block'){
    document.getElementById(divId1).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(divId2).style.display = 'block';
 }else{ 
   document.getElementById(divId2).style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById(divId1).style.display = 'block'
 }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="show-list-form" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');">
      <span class="placehoder-link"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add a list</span>
      <span class="placehoder-link"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another list</span>
      </a>
      <form id="add-list-form">
        <div class="form-inner-container">
        <input type="text" id="list-name" placeholder="Enter list title..." autocomplete="off">
        <input type="submit" value="Add List">
        <input type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></input>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toggle works but the function call needs to be changed.  In the solution below, I changed the name of the function to toggleDiv() and now it executes when called.

```js
var d = document;
d.g   = d.getElementById;

spans = d.getElementsByTagName("span");
window.onload = function(){
   spans[1].style.display='none';
   d.forms[0].style.display='none';
};

var clicked = 0;

function toggleDiv(divId1, divId2){
    clicked++;
    
    if( d.g( divId1 ).style.display == 'block'){
        d.g( divId1 ).style.display = 'none';
        d.g( divId2 ).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    { 
        d.g( divId2 ).style.display = 'none';
        d.g( divId1 ).style.display = 'block'
    }

    if ( clicked > 0) {
       spans[0].style.display='none';
       spans[1].style.display='block';
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="show-list-form" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');">         
<span class="placehoder-link"><i class="fas fa-plus">Add a list</i></span>
      <span class="placehoder-link"><i class="fas fa-plus">Add another list</span></i></a>
      <form id="add-list-form">
        <div class="form-inner-container">
        <input type="text" id="list-name" placeholder="Enter list title..." autocomplete="off" onmouseover="this.focus()" onmouseout="this.blur()">
        <input type="submit" value="Add List">
        <input type="button" style="font-style: italic" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form')" value="Close">
        </div>
      </form>
```

Note: one line of HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></input>
```

should be amended as follows:

```
<input type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');">
```

No reason to use `i` tags with an input button and the input tag does not need a closing tag.  If you must have *italics*, you could style the button and indicate an italic font.  Since this is a Close button, you should probably indicate that in the value attribute.

Also, the two span tags had superfluous `i` tags, so the code wraps them around the linked text values.

The code uses a static *clicked* variable to control display of the content of the `a` tag with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, @slevy1.  This answer worked the best for me because it includes code for toggling spans. However, I had to change this code  **spans = d.getElementsByTagName("span");**  to this code **spans = document.getElementsByClassName("placeholder");** and add class="placeholder" to spans in the html file to get it to switch between span links.

Answer (score 4):

Here, use `EventListener` and toggle that way.

```js
// Set up click events
var showList = document.getElementById("show-list-form");
var hideList = document.getElementById("closeForm");
var formElement = document.getElementById("add-list-form");

const toggle = (hide, show) => {
  hide.style.display = 'none';
  show.style.display = 'block';
};

showList.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  toggle(showList, formElement);
});

hideList.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  toggle(formElement, showList);
});

// Init
toggle(formElement, showList);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="show-list-form">
  <span class="placehoder-link"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add a list</span>
  <span class="placehoder-link"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another list</span>
</a>
<form id="add-list-form">
  <div class="form-inner-container">
    <input type="text" id="list-name" placeholder="Enter list title..." autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" value="Add List">
    <input id="closeForm" type="button"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></input>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: They just needed to change their onclicks to match the function and default the form to display:none.  Your rewrite does work though!  LOL.

Comment: @IamBatman last time I posted a fix that included inline javascript calls in the HTML I got roasted. :) you know how it is.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't change the onclicks to match your function.  Also on load, you need to display:none your form.

```js
function toggle_visibility(divId1, divId2){
 if(document.getElementById(divId1).style.display == 'block'){
    document.getElementById(divId1).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(divId2).style.display = 'block';
 }else{ 
   document.getElementById(divId2).style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById(divId1).style.display = 'block'
 }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="show-list-form" onclick="toggle_visibility('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');">
      <span class="placehoder-link"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add a list</span>
      <span class="placehoder-link"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another list</span>
      </a>
      <form id="add-list-form"  style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-inner-container">
        <input type="text" id="list-name" placeholder="Enter list title..." autocomplete="off">
        <input type="submit" value="Add List">
        <input type="button" onclick="toggle_visibility('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></input>
        </div>
      </form>
```